# Module Not Found Error for a module that is unrelated to what I'm trying to import

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import a module in Python, but I keep getting the same error message, and I don't understand where it's coming from. I have even tried running the line below in a new bank document, and it still came up with he same issue.

```
import fastscape
from fastscape.models import basic_model
```

The error message it shows is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\[redacted local file directory].py:2 in <module>
    import fastscape

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastscape\__init__.py:6 in <module>
    from . import processes

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastscape\processes\__init__.py:1 in <module>
    from .boundary import BorderBoundary

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastscape\processes\boundary.py:6 in <module>
    from .context import FastscapelibContext

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastscape\processes\context.py:1 in <module>
    import fastscapelib_fortran as fs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastscapelib_fortran'
```

Except, as far as I am aware, there is no `'fastscapelib_fortran'` in that model.

Comment: Is there a traceback that goes with that exception? If so, please edit the question to include that too.

Comment: You import some library, but those libraries have their own dependency so they also import some libraries and so on.. So you should focus on to install this module. it could be some version issues.

Comment: Would you believe me if i told you that following that link (and the tutorial provided by the people who made Fastscape) is how I ended up here? I've done the steps in conda, and adding `import fastscape` before `from fastscape.models import basic_model` does not change anything. I have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: The problem isn't what you've done before importing `fastscape`. The problem is (as can be seen from the traceback) that the `fastscape` module imports others that import `fastscapelib_fortran`. Since you don't have that installed, `fastscape` can't be imported

Comment: I understand you followed https://fastscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html, which says that `conda install fastscape -c conda-forge` should install all dependencies. I'm not sure why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documented
[install instructions](https://fastscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
works great.

```
$ conda create --name myproj
...
$ conda activate myproj
$
$ conda install fastscape -y -c conda-forge
...
$
$ python -c 'import fastscape'                                                                                               
$ python -c 'import fastscapelib_fortran'
$
$ conda list | grep fastscape                                                                                                
fastscape                 0.1.0beta3         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge                                                                                        
fastscapelib-f2py         2.8.3           py310h96b8b03_0    conda-forge
$ python --version
Python 3.10.8
```

The imports work fine, with no error.
Conda pulled in all the deps.

Comment: i'm getting the following  issues: `(myproj) C:\Users\name>python -c 'import fastscape'
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal(myproj) C:\Users\name>python -c 'import fastscape'
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` which goes away when I remove the space after `import`

Comment: `(myproj) C:\Users\namet>conda list | grep fastscape
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: On the OS's I use, mac + linux, `bash` accepts `'` single quotes for command arguments, and `which grep` reports /usr/bin/grep. In other environments you may need to use alternate quoting arrangements; `where search` might reveal where your string search tool is located. Or just eyeball the list output unfiltered, and visually grep for the relevant line.

Comment: thank you! turn out `Findstr` is what I was meant to be using instead of `grep`, and after sorting my working directories out, it all worked out.